# Fork, While loop semaphore control in C

Tags: c, fork, semaphore, fifo

In C, Im curious how to control the child to wait for the parent to finish doing all of its actions. In the example code I am writing to a named fifo in child and reading in the parent. Wrote the code in the post so don't be rough.

I tried doing it the code snippet below and it worked somewhat but the semaphore sequence eventually broke at some point. Is this possible, do I need more than 1 semaphore? It's indeterministic which process will go first, how can I make it deterministic to get input from the child first? I just started with semaphores and the concept is simple but Im having a hard time knowing when to post and when to wait.

```
sem_unlink("/queue");
sem_t queue = sem_open("/queue",O_CREAT,O_RDWR,1);
pid_t example_pid = fork();
switch(example_pid)
{
   case -1:
     example_pid = -1;
     exit(1);
   case 0:
       int write_fd = open(myfifo,O_WRONLY);
       while(1){
           sem_wait(queue);
           //Get some input
           write(write_fd,input,sizeof(input)); 
       }
   default:
      int read_fd = open(myfifo,O_RDONLY);
      while(1){
           read(read_fd,BUF,sizeof(BUF));
           //Do some actions from reading input
           sem_post(queue);
      }
}
```

Comment: I think I would need two semaphores so that the parent knows the child is done writing?

Comment: Normally it's the parent waiting for the child.

Comment: So would it be better to do the writing in the parent and perform the actions in the child?

Comment: You have a deadlock. The parent doesn't post to the semaphore until after it reads something from the FIFO. But the child doesn't write to the FIFO until after the parent posts to the semaphore.

Comment: @Olaf That's just waiting for termination. In other cases, it doesn't matter which is which.

Comment: I suspect this is an X/Y problem.  Why does the parent need a mechanism other than the FIFO to wait synchronize with the child?  Why does the child need to wait for the parent at all?

Comment: It doesn't deadlock when I run something very similar :O The semaphore is started at 1? child calls wait on it? writes?

Comment: Also, it is strange for a parent process and its forked child process to communicate via an external FIFO instead of directly via a pipe.

Comment: It helps because for my use, the named fifo needs to be opened elsewhere other than in the main. The code above just doesn't explain that

Comment: You need to know that anything you write into a pipe, can be read only once. If you have 2 read FDs consuming it, maybe the other one has "stolen" some data from it.